# Sheet dismiss gesture delay breaks subsequent sheet presentation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, modal-dialog

I am currently writing a project using SwiftUI and each button in a List presents a sheet. If I dismiss using the dismiss button and select another button in the list, the sheet presents without issues.

However, if I dismiss by swiping down and try to quickly select another button in the list, the sheet does not show unless I tap the button again.

I did some testing regarding this and I found that when I tap the button right after dismissing the sheet, `isPresented` is still true even though the sheet isn't shown on screen.

My conclusion was that with a dismiss button, `isPresented` was set to false immediately, but dismissing with a swipe gesture has a noticeable delay when updating `isPresented`. How would I remove this delay from the swipe gesture?

I tried using `sheet(item: )` as well, but some buttons tend to not present a sheet if I quickly dismiss and press a button.

Sample code is attached below. First, present the sheet, dismiss it with a swipe gesture and quickly select another button (or the same button) in the list. The sheet shouldn't present.

```swift
// Comment out the ContentView that you don't want to present
struct SheetItem: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let items = [
        SheetItem(name: "John"),
        SheetItem(name: "Dylan"),
        SheetItem(name: "Dave")
    ]

    @State private var isPresented = false
    @State private var selectedItem: SheetItem?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section("Uses isPresented for the sheet") {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                        Button(item.name) {
                            // This shows the sheet presentation state on button press
                            // print(isPresented)
                            selectedItem = item
                            isPresented.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Results")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            if let item = selectedItem {
                SheetView(item: item)
            } else {
                Text("Item not selected?")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let items = [
        SheetItem(name: "John"),
        SheetItem(name: "Dylan"),
        SheetItem(name: "Dave")
    ]

    @State private var isPresented = false
    @State private var selectedItem: SheetItem?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section("Uses isPresented for the sheet") {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                        Button(item.name) {
                            // This shows the sheet presentation state on button press
                            // print(selectedItem)
                            selectedItem = item
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Results")
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedItem) { item in
            SheetView(item: item)
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var item: SheetItem

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, \(item.name)")
            Button("Dismiss") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: try using `.sheet(item:...)` instead. There are many examples on SO and the net.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I updated the sample code using item. Doing the same behavior caused the view to lock up and the sheet refuses to present.

Comment: put the `.sheet(item:...)` outside the `List{...}`. Note in `SheetView`, you can also use `@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss`, with `Button("Dismiss") { dismiss() }`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine code updated. Same error still occurs. For the item view, try clicking the button, dismissing the sheet, and clicking the same button again (as stated in the initial post). The view will lock up.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue when I use `.sheet(item: $selectedItem)`, with the code you have in your second example. All works well for me. Note, I tested on ios-15, then now on io-16, both systems worked well.

Comment: Edited with a gif. This shows the issue, you have to be relatively quick with dismissal to trigger it. It's best achieved on a physical device.

Comment: Same problem. Tried adding `onDisappear` to the content - no success.

Comment: Thanks @workingdogsupportUkraine, putting on the outside solved for me.